# How can I use gettext in a kivy app on android?

Tags: python, kivy, gettext

I have a kivy app that uses a module from another package. The packages are organised as follows:

```
.
├── kivy_app
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── myapp-0.1-debug.apk
│   ├── buildozer.spec
│   └── kivy_app
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       ├── main.py
│       ├── python_pkg -> /home/jeff/projects/kivy_pkg/python_pkg/python_pkg
│       └── source
│           └── kivy_app.py
└── python_pkg
    └── python_pkg
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── locale
        │   └── en_GB
        │       └── LC_MESSAGES
        │           └── python_pkg.mo
        └── source
            └── version.py
```

The module kivy_app.py accesses version.py in python_pkg. This latter package uses a translation file based on gettext, set up in the normal way.

The application works perfectly on the PC, but when the app is run on an android device it crashes. The relevant lines in the logcat output are:

```
09-07 16:28:22.142 10274 10340 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/kivy_pkg/kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/gettext.py", line 524, in translation
09-07 16:28:22.142 10274 10340 I python  :  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'python_pkg'
```

I cannot find where gettext.py is trying to locate the mo files.  Can someone please suggest how I might change things so that it works?

PS It works if I set the fallback value to True in gettext.translation(), but then no translation gets done!

Comment: Did you do something to make the .mo file get included in the apk? Is it present if you check its expected location and print that in your code?

Comment: @inclement I have included mo files in the source.include_exts in buildozer.spec. The PC version seems to pick it up explicitly from the python_pkg package. As I said in my question, I do not know what is the expected location of mo in the APK, and so I cannot check it. I was hoping to put a print statement into gettext.py, but I cannot see how gettext.py gets into the APK either.

Comment: @inclement I have now added a line to print whether or not python_pkg.mo is in the expected location, and it is on the PC but IT IS NOT on the android APK! So it looks like the buildozer is not collecting the .mo file. My buildozer.spec includes the line: source.include_exts = py, kv, mo

Comment: Based on the directory structure you printed, the python_pkg directory inside your app is only  symlink to the real directory? What if you copy the directory instead of symlinking it?

Comment: @inclement I have tried this, but the only way I can get it to work on the PC is to place the python_pkg directory in the top kivy_app directory. This necessitates changes to the code in python_pkg module (which is not optimal) and it fails on Android with ModuleNotFouneError ... python_pkg

Answer (score 1):

I see that it is an old question, but recently I had the same problem: on PC it worked, on android crashed. And the output in the logcat was the same.

All .mo files were included in package. So, I've copied `gettext.py` to my project and added print-statements in function `find`. There is a part, where it goes through all possible languages, builds a path to .mo file and checks if it exists.

It appeared that on PC and android these language arrays are different. All I've got to do, was to change in my project locale directory name from `EN` to `en`, etc. Now it works.